# Identifying DDD Bounded Contexts and Structuring Project

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to get my head around Domain Driven Design and the examples I've seen seem to make sense but I am still unsure of how to apply them to my specific situation.

I am designing a CMS where a user can post/edit an article. These can then be viewed by other users who can also make comments, add tags etc. The question I have is, What are the bounded contexts in this situation. You can view users as either "Content Creators" or "Content Users".

As far as project structure goes I was planning on having for example, Project.Data (Model Classes), Project.Services, Project.Repositories etc. This is all very data centric, should I be splitting these by the bounded context they inhabit. If so how do you deal with shared objects such as an Article?

As usual when trying to get your head around new concepts, the examples make perfect sense until you try to apply the thinking to a real situation.

Any pointers or useful links would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a shared kernel with the core of the application and reference the other context to the shared kernel. I can't explain this better then Eric Evans does in his book.